# TestCafe Can't interact with websites that requires plotlyjs

Tags: reactjs, automated-tests, plotly, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are not able to interact with one web application using TestCafe, it continuously showing loading without error (Web app is using plotlyjs).
I have checked proxy and firewall as well for another application (which is not using plotlyjs) on same network it is working fine.

Error :
 Error on page "http://IP:Port":

Uncaught ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined

Testcafe --version 0.18.6
Chrome 63.0.3239
Windows 7.0.0

Tried with TestCafe CLI and UI, on both observed same issue.

Comment: I have checked from developer tool , there is no java script error on page.

Comment: I've tried to create a [simple test](https://gist.github.com/miherlosev/0bb85432e0ac574aa3a7a7191201852f) with `plotly.js` and all works good. Could you please provide a link to your application or create example to reproduce?

Comment: Application link is not available in public. one observational is that “plotly.js” is included in index.html file using script tag. can this cause issue ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem using your description. Create an example using https://codepen.io/#

Comment: @mlosev thanks for update, can you please share your ploty.js sample code. I can refer that.

Comment: i already done this in previous comment - see link https://gist.github.com/miherlosev/0bb85432e0ac574aa3a7a7191201852f

Comment: Thanks , I have tried test created by you it is not working for me Testcafe --version 0.18.6 Chrome 63.0.3239 Windows 7.0.0.  When i am executing the test browser only shows http://161.85.110.146:51060/browser/idle/39k1Lc4 url it is not redirecting to application url ,please let me know if you need any further detail for debugin

Comment: Try to run test on the latest Chrome version - 64.0.3282.167.

Answer (score 1):

My attempts to replicate this issue using the latest TestCafe version ([0.23.0](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/blog/testcafe-v0-23-0-released.html)) and Chrome (69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)) were unsuccessful.

I recommend that you update your tools and see how it works.

Comment: I will check this issue with latest version , thanks for update